# DocuSign Api - RadioGroup require one Radio element to be selected

Tags: c#, docusignapi, radio-group, required

I have a series of RadioGroups with two options (Radios) 'Yes' and 'No'. I would like to make the RadioGroup required such that one of the options need to be selected.

I can set the required property of each Radio to 'true' but then both must be selected.

How do I achieve this using the DocuSign Api?

---- EDIT

This appears only to be possible using the form designer. The API appears unable to handle this requirement currently.

I've used the designer to create a template and I'm able to achieve making a radio group required with needing to pre-fill an option (which results in a poor user experience and a high chance of inaccurate data). [image]

```
            RadioGroupTabs = new List<RadioGroup>
            {
                new RadioGroup
                {
                    DocumentId = "1",
                    RecipientId = "1",
                    GroupName = "InvestedInEISFundBefore",
                    RequireAll = "true",
                    Shared = "true",
                    Radios = new List<Radio>
                    {
                        new Radio
                        {
                            PageNumber = "7",
                            XPosition = "490",
                            YPosition = "277",
                            TabOrder = "17",
                            Value = "Yes"
                        },
                        new Radio
                        {
                            PageNumber = "7",
                            XPosition = "480",
                            YPosition = "277",
                            TabOrder = "18",
                            Value = "No"
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think what you want is to use the Select = true; in one and Selected = false in the other. The radioGroup automatically has logic to require exactly one radio button to be selected (thus it's not a checkbox, but a radio button!) so all you have to decide is how is the default state when the user just opens the envelope. Hope this makes sense.

Comment: Thanks - not the answer I was hoping for as this method could result in a user missing selecting the correct option. I'm going to leave this one open for another day or two to see if anyone knows of a way of achieving exactly what I want.

Comment: hmmm, I'm not sure what you are look for then. can you explain what you need? cause this seems to do what you want - set the default value

Comment: The problem with setting a default value is that the user isn't 'forced' to select the correct value and may just submit with the pre-selected value.  Believe it is possible to implement what I'm after using your WYSIWYG editor for docs.

Comment: hmmm, you want to "force" the user to select a specific value? sounds like you want it read-only?

Comment: Unhappy with the lack of support for this scenario but will accept this answer.